# The "References" parameter is not supported by the "XamlGTask" task

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Trying to lean Xamarin in vs2017

Doing the Quickstart

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows

After the project is created, you have to update the nugget packages, to fix the errors on "System"

This left me in a non compiling state. So I manually uninstalled and reinstalled the Xamarin.Forms and NetStandard Nuget package via the command line tool.

It then compiled and failed to deploy complaining about .netstandard. So I manually installed the .NetStandardLibrary nutget package.

It then compiled and deployed exactly once.

Now I'm getting a

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4064 The "References" parameter is not supported by the "XamlGTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.    XQuickStart C:\Users\Brown.ericw.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.6.0.264807\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets 90

Error.

How do I fix this?

Is Xamarin always this flakey? I mean this is a Hello world quick start, it shouldn't' be rocket science to get it working.

Comment: Good call. that seems to have fixed it.

If you add it as an answer, i'll mark it accepted., Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you did a lot of things that might have corrupted your project.

Try to clean solution & delete `Obj` and `Bin` folder & restart visual studio.

If you still have the prob, you should check if you don't have a `reference` in your `Standard Class Library` that has nothing to do here (like a ref to your droid project or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

VS somtimes have this kind of flakey issue. When you Make sure the code is ok, but VS is still promote some errors. You could refer to the following ways.

1. Clean your project, then re-build your project.
2. If you still get this error, close your VS, then open the project, delete all `bin` and `obj` folders in this project, Note:If you write a forms project, you should delete three times (drod,ios, PCL), open the prject, re-build your project in the end.
3. If above steps.it is not work, please delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in this project firstly, copy this project to another PC that installed VS, run this code.